# Kotlin Generics return type to match with receiver

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am trying to create a function that returns the default value if the receiver is null for the numbers. However, when I am checking the type of the received value, it is not matching with the receiver, instead it is matching with the default value I have passed as the argument.

```
fun <T : Number> T?.orDefault(value: T): T = this ?: value
```

Testing on above function with below code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b: Double? = null
    val default : Int = -1
    val orDefault = b.orDefault(default)
    println(orDefault)
    println(orDefault.javaClass.name)
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
// Output:
-1
java.lang.Integer
```

When I tried it by introducing another `J` that extends `T`, this still fails. Running with above mentioned main method still fails.

```
fun <T : Number, J : T> T?.orDefault(value: J): T = this ?: (value as T)

// Output:
-1
java.lang.Integer
```

In none of the cases it returns the double. What is wrong here?

**EDIT**:

I ended up doing something like this:

```
fun <T : Number, J : Number> T?.orDefault(value: J): T = this ?: (value as T)
```

This way, it make sure the return type is same as the receiver type. However, only downfall is for Null `Int` receiver it will accept `Double` as default and cast to `Int` to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, did something like this:

```
fun <T : Number, J : Number> T?.orDefault(value: J): T = this ?: (value as T)
```

This works without overriding all the number types and returns the correct type.

The only thing is it can aceept any default value from Number type. Like for Int, it can accept the double value as the default one and return it's int representation.

Answer (score 2):

In your first case, `orDefault()` is expecting the same type (`T`) for both receiver and parameter.  So when you call it with a `Double` receiver and an `Int` parameter, the compiler infers their closest common superclass (`Number`) for the type parameter `T`.  It then returns the given `Int` directly, as you see.

And although your second case looks more like what you want, I think it's still inferring `Number` for `T`, so the cast doesn't have any effect.

Ultimately, I don't think you'll be able to do what you want with only one extension function.  You can't cast an `Int` to a `Double` in Kotlin (unlike Java); you'd need to call its `toDouble()` method.  And you'd need to code that up separately for each receiver type.

Comment: That's sad.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not the optimal solution here. Since `Number` only has 7 subclasses you are better of overloading your extension function like this:

**1st way:**

```
fun Int?.orDefault(value: Int) = this ?: value
fun Double?.orDefault(value: Double) = this ?: value
// do the same for Float, Long, Char, Short and Byte
```

This will yield exactly the desired behaviour.

```
val default : Int = -1
val orDefault = b.orDefault(default.toDouble())
```

Note: You need to cast `default` to `Double`, since the receiver is `Double` it expects a `Double` as default.

Output:

> -1.0
>   double

**2nd way**

If you want to accept any `Number` and return it casted to the receiver's type do this:

```
fun Int?.orDefault(value: Number) = this ?: value.toInt()
fun Double?.orDefault(value: Number) = this ?: value.toDouble()
// do the same for Float, Long, Char, Short and Byte
```